# Suppress All Messages/Warnings with Readr read_csv function

Tags: r, markdown, suppress-warnings, readr, suppressmessage

I am creating a rmarkdown pdf report. I used read_csv function from readr package to import some csv files in a folder. I used SuppressMessages/Warnings functions to hide all warnings/messages, but I still get the messages as below when trying to import multiple files:

It seems SuppressMessages/Warnings don't work on the parsing warnings.

```
## Parsed with column specification:
## cols(
## .default = col_character(),
## `Constant USD - Accrued Sum` = col_number(),
## `Units Sold Sum` = col_number()
## )
```

Because the report is aimed for non-technical audience, the warning messages can be a distraction. What can I do to keep this message from showing?

Answer (score 30):

Just add `col_types = cols()` in the `read_csv()` function call

```
read_csv("path/to/file", col_types = cols())
```

Comment: There is still the message saying `i Using "','" as decimal and "'.'" as grouping mark. Use read_delim() for more control.`

Comment: @Julien: It seems that this cannot be silenced from within the package see [source](https://github.com/tidyverse/readr/blob/eda42c48d53025f230244d4d8c16ff4c83252a06/R/read_delim.R#L340) as it only depends on locale. You can switch to `read_delim()`

Answer (score 8):

Add `message=FALSE` to the chunk header:

````
```{r message=FALSE}
library("readr")
test <- read_csv("example.csv")
```
````

Answer (score 5):

#### Use `show_col_types = FALSE` to silence col type messages

This is silent:

```
library(readr)
df <- read_csv(readr_example("chickens.csv"), show_col_types = FALSE)
```

Whereas `read_csv(readr_example("chickens.csv"))` returns:

```
Rows: 5 Columns: 4                                                                                                                            
── Column specification ───────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Delimiter: ","
chr (3): chicken, sex, motto
dbl (1): eggs_laid

ℹ Use `spec()` to retrieve the full column specification for this data.
ℹ Specify the column types or set `show_col_types = FALSE` to quiet this message.
```